# What "number of bytes written" should my io.Writer return when it intentionally does not write all the bytes it is passed

Tags: go

I want to create a struct that implements `io.Writer`, ie `Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)`. The struct will omit certain bytes that is passed to it and thus not actually write all the bytes that is passed in the `p` parameter. (The actual purpose isn't important, but it could for example be to ignore the first 10 bytes written, ignore every second byte or something else that alters the number of bytes written from what the caller passed to the method).

[The documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) for `io.Writer`'s `Write` method says the following (emphasis mine):

> Write writes len(p) bytes from p to the underlying data stream. It
>   returns the number of bytes written from p (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any
>   error encountered that caused the write to stop early. **Write must
>   return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p)**. Write must not modify
>   the slice data, even temporarily.

What should I return as the `n` value? To comply with the documentation, on success I should return `len(p)`. However, the method might actually not have written that many bytes, and the return value will be "wrong".

Comment: `gzip.Writer`'s destination gets fewer bytes than its input, but it still reports the length of the input. It's answering "how many bytes of input were successfully handled?" not "how many bytes went to the destination?" If you need to expose the number somehow, I suggest exposing it outside the `Writer` interface--e.g., your struct exposes `OutputByteCount int` or something.

Comment: That's a good point about `gzip.Writer`. I should have thought about checking that and see what it does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On success, return len(p).

The [function called](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7e0165b2f1a912a06e381e91f0f4e495f4ac3736/drivers/char/mem.c#L675) when you write to /dev/null returns the number of bytes that you tried to "write" to it. It never actually writes anything, but it properly *handles* data being sent to it.

I would assume that in your case, you should only return n < len(p) if your writer was unable to properly *handle* all of the bytes sent to it.

Then, the documentation for your writer should **very clearly** state what data is and is not written. People using your function need to know what data will be retrievable after the write is finished.

Comment: `/dev/null` is a function? I suspect that's not what you meant.

Comment: @KeithThompson first, I should note that for a moment I thought your name was Ken Thompson, and nearly had a heart attack. Second, I will update my post to clarify. I was actually referring to the function in source for the driver used for the /dev/null device.

Comment: I believe I have now lost track of the number of times I've been mistaken for Ken Thompson. (We're even both gray-bearded Unix hackers.)